# Find upper left of image after resizing to fit screen

Tags: python, image, algorithm, python-2.7, image-resizing

I have a problem I haven't been able to figure out-

Say I have an image of arbitrary dimensions. I resize it so that it fits inside 1024x768 while keeping the aspect ratio. I center it on the screen. After doing this, how can I find where the upper left corner will end up?

So, if the image is wider than it is tall, we end up with something like
[image: this]

The green rectangle started at a different size. It was resized to fit the pink rectangle. I want to find the upper left corner of the green rectangle.

I wrote a bunch of notes and drew a bunch of diagrams, but I'm getting all the wrong answers. Can someone explain how to do this? I'm using python 2.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let `w`,`h` be the size of your image.

To fit the width of 1024, we must scale the image by:

```
>>> r=1024./w
```

However, if the image is taller, after scaling it by `r`, its height won't fit the screen, so in this case the scaling factor is:

```
>>> if h*r > 768: r=768./h
```

The coordinate of the upper left corner of the scaled image is:

```
>>> (1024-w*r)*0.5,(768-h*r)*0.5
```

Edit:

A handy function to compute the topleft point (works in Python 2.x as well):

```
def topLeft(w,h,screenw=1024,screenh=768):
    r=float(screenw)/float(w)
    if h*r > screenh: r=float(screenh)/float(h)
    return (screenw-w*r)*0.5,(screenh-h*r)*0.5
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for the quick response!

Comment: Wait, wouldn't either the final x or the final y be 0 because it's pressed up against the edge? I think this is the lower right hand corner, maybe... I forgot to mention, I'm counting the coordinates from the top left.

Comment: Yes, one of the two coordinates is always 0, because you are fitting to screen (because `r` is either `1024/w` or `768/h`, so if you substitute `r` in `(1024-w*r)/2,(768-h*r)/2` you get either `(0,768-h*1024/w)` or `1024-w*768/h,0`). Top left coordinate of the screen is (0, 0).

Comment: OK. So the coordinate is either `(1024-w*r)/2, 0` or `(768-h*r)/2, 0` depending on which was taller.

Comment: When I put in `(1024, 768)` I get `(0, 0)` but if I then put in the dimensions of an image such as `(1990, 1325)`, I get `512, 384`

Comment: OH `w` and `h` are supposed to be the resized dimensions, not original ones, makes much more sense. I feel stupid now.

Comment: NO. `w` and `h` are original img size. `w*r` and `h*r` are the scaled image sizes.  `topLeft(1990, 1325) == (0.0, 43.09547738693465)` (check my edit)

Comment: Ok, figured it out, it's a python2 vs python3 thing. I'm using 2.7. I get the desired output using python 3, but the wrong output using python 2.7

Comment: I'll figure out how to convert it.

Comment: Oh, sorry for that! I use Python 3 by default. I should have tested that in Python 2 since you have tagged the question with Python 2.x. I added a version for Python 2.x!

Comment: Yep. I'm trying to figure it out now. I would probably be using python 3, but I'm doing this to run on iOS, and I'm using pythonista which only supports 2.7

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81811/discussion-between-luke-taylor-and-mescalinum).